# Should we need to implement "merge related information posted as answers to the question"?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

**Background**

Recently I see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40011390/how-can-i-get-single-data-from-menus-when-i-click-moreover-add-the-data-that-i, and I found that the OP either intentionally or accidentally posted relevant or extra information as answers instead editing his question properly (it is done by 1 rep user).

Since this is the first encounter for me, I'm curious how moderators will manage/treat that kind of question where extra information provided by OP scattered between posted answers instead of putting all together on a question, since AFAIK the related ones should be added into the question as edit merge (and the answers probably cleaned up as a result).

**Problem Statement**

1. At this present, should we need to raise flag and inform moderators when similar scenarios found for next time, and what additional actions should be taken as plain users?
2. Should SO (and entire SE) have "merge related info posted by OP in answer as question edit" feature or flag reason to handle the scenario above?
3. If OP's answers containing related info to his question will deleted/pruned as part of merge process into his question, could it be taken as consideration to suspend his ability to post answers at certain time (a.k.a answer ban)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moderators already have such a tool. It deletes the answer and automatically incorporates it into the question as an edit with a couple clicks. But users are still capable of doing this themselves - edit the information into the question and then flag as not an answer. Wait for it to be deleted. Problem solved.

I never found this feature particularly useful and rarely used it because the text usually needed cleanup and further edits when incorporating into the question. So I always just do it the manual way anyways. This feature is more an artifact from the days when only moderators could handle not an answer flags and they needed a one-click button that would be done with it quickly when processing the queue. It's outdated and doesn't quite hit the mark most of the time.